# nextjs13 returns FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, next.js

I'm using nextjs v13 and firebase.

But it returns the error

[2023-06-11T09:01:15.911Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.22.0): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x7ad7511e error. Code: 7 Message: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

- error RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 0
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
  at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:343:11)
  at ServerResponse.writeHead (D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\compression\index.js:46:263)
  at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:334:8)
  at ServerResponse.end (D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\compression\index.js:22:749)
  at sendResponse (D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\server\send-response.js:49:30)
  at doRender (D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:969:62)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1161:28)
  at async D:\react\soccer-best11\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:99:36 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
  }

[image]

My code is

[Firebase rule]

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

[code]

1. app/api/boards/route.ts

```
import { db } from '../../config/firebase';
import { getDocs, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Board } from '@/app/types/Board';

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const boardsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'boards');
    const data = await getDocs(boardsCollectionRef);
    const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    })) as Board[];
    return NextResponse.json(filteredData);
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const data = await req.json();
    const boardsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'boards');
    await addDoc(boardsCollectionRef, data);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }
}
```

2. app/config/firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

3. app/boards/write/page.tsx

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Board } from '../../types/Board';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Create = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      redirect('/signin?callbackUrl=/protected/client');
    },
  });

  const tempData = {
    email: session?.user?.email!,
    userId: session?.user?.id!,
    title: 'post test',
    description: 'tttaaa',
    like: 0,
    dislike: 0,
    players: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    createdAt: '2022-09-19T05:50:45.043Z',
  };
  const addBoard = async (board: Board) => {
    return await axios.post('/api/boards', board, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.accessToken}`,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="btn-blue"
        onClick={async () => await addBoard(tempData)}
      >
        create
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

1. I don't want to change firebase rule to all true.
   I want to use addDocs only with login condition. (when auth.currentUser isn't null)
   Plz No allow read, write: if true; !
   (If read, write: if true, it works well)
2. I don't want to move route.ts's code to page.tsx
   ex: move

```
const data = await req.json();
const boardsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'boards');
await addDoc(boardsCollectionRef, data);
```

that code to page.tsx.

How can I solve it?